# Execute two while loop one after another for same mysqli_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop, foreach

Please Help Me, How can I Run two While Loop one after another. I want to get all the rows of database. If I put the manual-control DIV inside first while loop it shows the whole div separately. and when placed it outside it do nothing. Please rewrite the code.

### I want to get value like this_

```
<div class="img-slider-container">      
<div class="img-slide active">
   <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="Image">
   <div class="img-info">
      <h2>Heading 1</h2>
      <p>Image Text 1</p>
    </div>
 </div>

<div class="img-slide">
   <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="Image">
   <div class="img-info">
      <h2>Heading 2</h2>
      <p>Image Text 2</p>
    </div>
 </div> <!--Continue-->

 <div class="manual-control">
    <div class="slide-btn 1"></div>
    <div class="slide-btn 2"></div> <!--Continue-->
 </div>
```

### My Code Sample is given bellow_

```
<div class="img-slider-container">
        <?php
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbImadeSlide"; 
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            header("Location: index.php?error=sqlerror");
            exit();
        }
        else{
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

            if ($resultCheck > 0){
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    echo '

                        <div class="img-slide '.$row["imageStatus"].'">
                            <img src="img/'.$row["imageName"].'" alt="Image">
                            <div class="img-info">
                                <h2>'.$row["imageHeader"].'</h2>
                                <p>'.$row["imageText"].'</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>';
                       
                     
                } 
                    echo '<div class="manual-control">';
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                        echo '<div class="slide-btn '.$row["imageId"].'"></div>';}
                    echo '</div>';
            } else{
                echo "<div class='no_result'>No Photos To Slide</div>";
            }
        }
    ?>
```

### But the code just repeat first while loop like this_

```
<div class="img-slider-container">      
    <div class="img-slide active">
       <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="Image">
       <div class="img-info">
          <h2>Heading 1</h2>
          <p>Image Text 1</p>
        </div>
     </div>

    <div class="img-slide">
       <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="Image">
       <div class="img-info">
          <h2>Heading 2</h2>
          <p>Image Text 2</p>
        </div>
     </div> <!--Continue-->

     <div class="manual-control">
        <!--Nothing Shows-->
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: either store the recordset as a variable which you can process many times or use [data_seek](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php) to rewind the recordset before next while loop

Answer (score -1):

Without keep all the rows in array you can simply do this by **`foreach`** loop.

Just replace

`while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){`  **to**  `foreach($result as $row){`

Your code may look like:

```
<div class="img-slider-container">
    <?php
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbImadeSlide"; 
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        header("Location: index.php?error=sqlerror");
        exit();
    }
    else{
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if ($resultCheck > 0){
            foreach($result as $row){
                echo '

                    <div class="img-slide '.$row["imageStatus"].'">
                        <img src="img/'.$row["imageName"].'" alt="Image">
                        <div class="img-info">
                            <h2>'.$row["imageHeader"].'</h2>
                            <p>'.$row["imageText"].'</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>';


            } 
                echo '<div class="manual-control">';
                foreach($result as $row){
                    echo '<div class="slide-btn '.$row["imageId"].'"></div>';}
                echo '</div>';
        } else{
            echo "<div class='no_result'>No Photos To Slide</div>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I don't understand it. Why prepare if you are using `mysqli_query`? Remove `mysqli_query` from your code completely.